# Notepad++ how to type <html> and have it print whole layout

Tags: html, notepad++

I've been using notepad++ for a while and decided to try out another text editor...sublime text. I like how in that editor, if a document is saved as .html, you can type into the editor

```
html
```

then you can press the tab button and it automatically comes out as:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Seeing as I don't want to pay the $70 it costs for sublime text, I was wondering if notepad++ had a feature like that. Maybe a plugin that I'm not familiar with? Anybody know of such a thing? Let me know! Please!

Answer (score 5):

Try [Zen Coding for notepad++](https://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/downloads/detail?name=Zen.Coding-Notepad%2b%2b.v0.7.zip&can=2&q=), from their documentation:

> Zen Coding is an editor plugin for high-speed HTML, XML, XSL (or any
>   other structured code format) coding and editing. The core of this
>   plugin is a powerful abbreviation engine which allows you to expand
>   expressions—similar to CSS selectors—into HTML code. For example:

`div#page>div.logo+ul#navigation>li*5>a`...can be expanded into:

```
<div id="page">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <ul id="navigation">
                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                <li><a href=""></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 to this answer as well, this has a bit steeper learning curve in my opinion than webedit, but it works well and once picked up has great potential.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/webedit-use-text-expansion-integrate-code-snippets-into-notepad/

WebEdit is an extension for notepad++ made for web developers that comes preloaded with several text expansions specific to web development. It's also configurable to allow you to add your own text expansions if there isn't one you see fit to do the job preloaded.

Hope that helps!